# Was Sarah Connor in 'The Terminator' previously spelled Sarah Conner?

Tags: the-terminator

Whenever I watch The Terminator, these days, Arnie is searching for Sarah Connor (phone book listings etc.).  But I'm sure that, years ago, her name was Sarah Conner.  Was there a name change at some point?

Comment: Can you point to a _single_ place where the name was ever "Conner"?  (You can check out the credits for the movies and TV show on [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/find?q=terminator&s=tt&ref_=fn_al_tt_mr).)

Comment: @DavidW  Only in my memory, I'm afraid,  that's why I asked here.  Connor is the standard Irish surname and I've known a few over the years, that's why Conner stood out, to me, in 1985 when I first saw the film.  I have a vague recollection of someone mentioning that it was changed in later releases because it was so obviously non-standard - but it's only a vague recollection.  Trying to find "Sarah Conner" is pretty much impossible on the internet.

Comment: @Dave Gremlin - When you say you might've heard the name was changed for later releases, what specifically do you mean by "later releases"...? Blu-ray releases? DVD releases? VHS releases? TV airings? Theatrical showings? Trying to establish how far back we need to go to establish whether such a change did or didn't occur.

Comment: @LogicDictates  The reson I asked the question is because I'm really not sure about this, but I think (and could be wrong) that I saw a program in the 90s, possibly a review of T2, where it was mentioned that the name was changed for T2 because it wasn't the standard Irish form of the name.

Comment: @Dave Gremlin - If they only changed the name for the release of T2 in 1991, this ought to be a pretty well-known fact, since many people (myself included) would have seen the film before T2's release. Not only have I never seen a version with a different name, personally, but there's no reference to such a change on the [IMDB trivia page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088247/trivia/) for the film.

Comment: @DaveGremlin - It certainly wasn't changed for T2

Comment: "Conner stood out, to me, in 1985 when I first saw the film" — where in The Terminator do you remember seeing the name written down? In a phone book close-up? In the closing credits?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite  I think it was when Arnie runs his finger down the list of Connors in the phone book, but that doesn't seem right because there would be have to be more than one _Sarah Conner_, which would be really odd!

Comment: I there only was a world wide computer network allowing us to gather information… https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wNTIPaBbPI&t=24s

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?v=2wNTIPaBbPI&t=21s is a little closer. James Cameron might have gone back and re-shot that one bit for the VHS release, for all we know. I notice there is a "Michale Connor"; I've never seen that first name before, although apparently [it's Hebrew](http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/1/Michale) and also [a village in Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michale).

Comment: @DaveGremlin Could you be thinking of [Conner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conner_Peripherals) disk drives?

Comment: The simplest explanation is usually the correct one. Seems obvious that it was originally "Conner" with an 'e', as you remember, from the original timeline in which Judgement Day happens. Changing history obviously created harmonics which echoed further  into the past, changing the spelling, but leaving your memory intact. Congratulations on making out of that timeline.

Comment: "Conner" is the last name of the family from Roseanne, could you be getting your fictions mixed up?

Comment: @Josh  That may well be the case!

Comment: Nothing to back this up with, but perhaps because the implications of each spelling are vastly different. Connor means 'wise', Conner hints at more underhand means of gaining income. [I don't see how that really relates to the Roseanne family, but hey;)

Comment: @JesseM I'd reward you with a bounty on that comment, if it were possible.   Nicely done!

Comment: The Terminator just pronounced it like that, some accent thing, or whatever.

Comment: @Mithoron  Arnold Schartzenegger's famous hillbilly drawl :)   https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-Arnold-Schwarzenegger-was-not-allowed-to-dub-the-German-version-of-Terminator-2-because-his-accent-would-be-considered-by-Germans-as-being-too-rural-and-it-would-be-ridiculous-for-The-T-800-to-sound?share=1

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Sarah was certainly Connor (with an O) in the [original film treatment](http://bythelens.org/screenplays/TerminatorTreatment.pdf), written several years before the first draft screenplay and dated July, 1982.

[image]

This hasn't changed by the time the [4th draft screenplay](https://thescriptsavant.com/pdf/TheTerminator.pdf) was written in March, 1984.

[image]

Aside from Internet OCR failures, there don't appear to be any references to her as Sarah Conner (with an e) in any of the official documents.

Comment: That looks pretty conclusive.

Comment: @DaveGremlin - I'm having a hunt around to see if she was ever mis-named on anything official.

Comment: Mandela Effect here: I had the same notion for years

Comment: @DannyMcG - There's plenty of online scripts and copies where there's been an OCR fail, like [here](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Terminator_Treatment.txt) and [here](https://sfy.ru/?script=terminator), which is why it's always worth hunting down the original.

Comment: This is about as definitive an answer as you could get.  I guess I saw one of the OCR fails at some point, or I'm confusing T1 and some other name change somewhere.

Comment: @DannyMcG  We must have been abducted by the same aliens :)

Comment: @DaveGremlin I assume you are both humans and as such subject to the same brain farts, including (but not limited to) the Mandela Effect.

Comment: @stannius “I assume you are both humans” — ask the other two Sarah Conners if that’s a good idea! Oh you can’t, they’re dead!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite in *this* timeline